# How to avoid small value assignment in pyomo NonNegativeReals?

Tags: python, pyomo

I am getting very small value to variable of NonNegativeReals, this makes my Binary varible to 1.
Bound of NonNegativeReals variable is 0 to 100 suppose.
How can I avoid this?

```
x = Var(bounds=(0,capacity_value), domain=NonNegativeReals, name='v',initialize=0)
x_binary = Var(within=Binary,name='binary_'+'v',initialize=0)
model.constraints.add(expr=x_binary*x==x)
```

2 PlantA 111 6.430220407951851e-08      B_ 1.0

2 PlantA 222 1.8079267671231208e-06      B_ 1.0

This value should go into the other variable.

Comment: These are integrality conditions and it depends upon each solver. For instance, in gurobi you control it using `IntFeasTol` parameter that you can pass from `pyomo` to solver: `solver = SolverFactory('gurobi')` and then `solver.solve(model, options={'IntFeasTol':1E-9}`.But, TBH, 6.43E-8 is pretty much zero